# Printing from free version of CartoDB?

Tags: printing, carto

I am  trying to export the maps into a MS Word document and cannot find a way of doing it. Currently  I am having to screen print to Photoshop and then cut and paste into a document. The problem is the narrow viewable screen area limits what can be seen at once and the resolution of this method is poor.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Export image option in order to download your map as a .PNG image file.

[image: Export image modal]